# how to get all item id in spinner Activity from recyclerview Activity after click

Tags: android, json, android-recyclerview, android-volley, android-spinner

see image click on first [First Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yljo7.jpg)    ,get value on second  [second image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zmx0s.jpg)I want to get All item id in spinner when I clicked on recycler
view any selected item and get all item id get from recyclerview list.

**My Code :**

```
public class Assigned extends AppCompatActivity
{
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.assign);
        recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.cardList);
        final LinearLayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(context);
        layoutManager.setOrientation(LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        model_joblists = new ArrayList<>();
        recyclerView.addOnItemTouchListener(
                new RecyclerItemClickListener(context, new RecyclerItemClickListener.OnItemClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onItemClick(View view, int position) {
                        Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), JobSubmission_First.class);
                        HashMap<String, String> selected_item = Item_List.get(position);
                        intent.putExtra("job_no",selected_item.get(JOB_NO));
                        intent.putExtra("job_description",selected_item.get(DESCRIPTION_NAME));
                        startActivity(intent);
                    }
                })
        );
        getDataNew();
    }
    private void getDataNew()
    {
        String url = "http://10.54.103.8:4067/services/Webservices/joblisting";
        HashMap<String, String> user = session.getUserDetails();
        String token = user.get(SessionManager.KEY_TOKEN);
        Log.e("token ", token);
        final String role = user.get(SessionManager.KEY_ROLE);
        Log.e("role", role);
        String user_id = user.get(SessionManager.KEY_USERID);
        Log.e("user_id", String.valueOf(user_id));
        Map<String, String> params = new HashMap();
        params.put(KEY_TOKEN, token);
        params.put(KEY_ROLE, role);
        params.put(KEY_ID, user_id);
    JSONObject parameters = new JSONObject(params);
    final ProgressDialog loading = ProgressDialog.show(this, "Loading Data", "Please wait...", false, false);
    JsonObjectRequest jsonRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.POST, url, parameters, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(JSONObject response)
        {
            try {
                String req = response.getString("err-code");
                if (0 == Integer.parseInt(req)) {
                    Log.e("response mila", response.toString());
                    ParseData(response);
                    loading.dismiss();
                }
            }
            catch (JSONException e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                error.printStackTrace();
                //TODO: handle failure
            }
        });
        jsonRequest.setRetryPolicy(new DefaultRetryPolicy(
            5000,
            DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_MAX_RETRIES,
            DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_BACKOFF_MULT))
        Volley.newRequestQueue(this).add(jsonRequest);
    }
    private void ParseData(JSONObject Object)
    {

        try {
            JSONArray jsonArray = Object.getJSONArray("job_details");
            for (int m = 0; m < jsonArray.length(); m++) {
                Model_joblist model_joblist= new Model_joblist();
                JSONObject   jsonObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(m);
                HashMap<String, String> item = new HashMap<String, String>();
                String job=jsonObject.getString("job_no");
                String jobdes=jsonObject.getString("job_description");
                item.put(JOB_NO, jsonObject.getString(JOB_NO));
                item.put(DESCRIPTION_NAME,jsonObject.getString(DESCRIPTION_NAME));
                Item_List.add(item);
                jobdesnext.add(jsonObject.getString("job_description"));
                jobno_spineer.add(jsonObject.getString("job_no"));
                Log.e("spineer value", jobno_spineer.toString());
                model_joblists.add(model_joblist);
            }
            String from[]={JOB_NO,DESCRIPTION_NAME};
            int to[]={R.id.textSpinner,R.id.jobdescription};
            spinnerAdapter=new SimpleAdapter(getApplicationContext(),Item_List,R.layout.assign,from,to);

        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        ContactAdapter adapter2 = new ContactAdapter(model_joblists);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter2);
    }
}
```

Comment: you just want ids list to sent it in next screen>

Comment: yes i want id and its description...i want to set all id in spinner ,when i choose id in spinner its description changes....so its depend on id

i used hashmap..i stored both value in hashmap but not geting in next class in spinner

Comment: you talking about these `String job=jsonObject.getString("job_no");
                String jobdes=jsonObject.getString("job_description");`

Comment: hi ..i have another question...how can l implement my android app..for admin home screen different and users home screen different except login screen in same app??